# How to restrict folder permissions of Gitlab shell executor on Windows

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm mostly new to Gitlab and the Windows command line. I set up a Gitlab runner on my windows PC and it works well. However, I want to restrict it so that it can only access the folder I set it up in, and all subfolders. What is the most reliable way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "it can only access the folder I set it up in, and all subfolders"

Answer (score 1):

Since the [GitLab runner is installed as a service](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html), you could:

- create a second Windows account
- use that account to register your service

  ```
  gitlab-runner install --user ENTER-YOUR-SECOND-USERNAME --password ENTER-YOUR-SECOND-PASSWORD
  ```
- protect the folder (and its content) you want with the second user account.

By default, the second account would not have read/write access to at least your own C:\user\login, provided you [change the File and Folder permission setting](https://superuser.com/a/1115604/141).

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I was looking for